# How to pass LinkedList object in java between classes

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I have two java classes in two different files (Crawler.java and A2ZurlRead.java).
Inside A2ZUrlRead.java I have the Following:

```
 private LinkedList<String> issuesUrlsToVisit; // A queue of issues URLs to
                                                // visit
...

public A2ZUrlReader(String name) throws IOException {
    // Grab all actual issues urls into new queue.
    this.issuesUrlsToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
            readContent();
    ....
}
...
...
public void readContent() throws IOException {
    ....
    ....
    // Add it LinkedList
    issuesUrlsToVisit.add("http://www.sourceforge.com" + url);
    ...
}

// return set of collected actual issues' urls
public LinkedList<String> getIssuesUrls() {
    return this.issuesUrlsToVisit;
}
```

on the second class file "Crawler.java" i have created object of A2ZUrlRead.java as follow:

```
private void read(String urlpath) {

    System.out.println("Reading ... " + urlpath);
    try {
        // Grab the URLs content for issues
        A2ZUrlReader url = new A2ZUrlReader(urlpath);
        this.issuesURLsToVistit = url.getIssuesUrls();
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println("Problem reading from " + urlpath + " " + e);
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public LinkedList<String> getIssuesURLs(){
    return this.issuesURLsToVistit;
}
public void print(){
    System.out.println("here !!");
    while(!this.issuesURLsToVistit.isEmpty()){
        String temp = this.issuesURLsToVistit.removeFirst();
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

From the main function i tried to use print() method to print the LinkedList values but it shows empty results ?!! i tried to print the LinkedList values from the original class it success !!

Any body can help please...

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Where do you call read(urlPath) of Crawler?

Comment: from the main function

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the object, but never calling the method that fills in your linked list before calling `getIssuesUrls()`.

Something like this maybe?

```
A2ZUrlReader url = new A2ZUrlReader(urlpath);
url.readContent();
this.issuesURLsToVistit = url.getIssuesUrls();
```

Comment: No, readContent() function is already called inside A2ZUrlReader constructor.

Comment: Thanks for updating, given the current code sample I don't see where the error would be.

Comment: I realized the problem was caused by the diversity between linkedlists in different classes. The solution was easy just add the values for the new list into the old one for each.

I just add new method:

public void setLinkedList(LinkedList<String> newList){
    this.issuesURLsToVistit.addAll(newList);
}
And it solved the problem...

Comment: Great!  Answer your own question (with full details and edits to your original example) and you can accept it as an answer, and increase your rep.